# How can I automate this division of my data set in R?

Tags: r, loops, iteration

How do I get a loop which performs these actions in R?

Map 33 doesn't exist.

```
map1 <- dat %>%
  filter(map == 1)
map2 <- dat %>%
  filter(map == 2)
map3 <- dat %>%
  filter(map ==3)
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't need to use multiple steps, just use `split` to return a `list` of data.frames

```
lst1 <- split(dat, dat$map)
names(lst1) <- paste0("map", names(lst1))
```

It is better not to create multiple objects.  But if we need, use `list2env`

```
list2env(lst1, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Thank you!!

The only thing missing is to name the parts of the list after the actual map number. As I wrote, some, like map 33, are missing. If I perform your code, map34 becomes 33

Comment: @Theresa just change the `seq_along` to `names(lst1)` updated